# Rails - Controller Action can only be executed by JS call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my view file, I use a `collection_select` with an `:onchange => remote_function` that execute another action from the same controller (the action will eventually update the page content)

I'd like this action to be only accessible when called by the JS but not when the corresponding route is directly entered as an URL in the browser.

Any idea how I could do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `request.xhr?` to check the request type, either its AJAX request or others (post, get). It returns true or false. If true you can perform the action.

Answer (score 1):

You could use respond_with and respond_to

```
class MyController
  respond_to :js

  def index
    respond_with(@users = User.all)
  end
end
```